# Open Modal javascript with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I would like to create a horizontal scroll like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp but when the user click in the link a pop up opens. Thanks!

Comment: Yes? So what is your question and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. First make a pop-up with HTML and CSS
2. Use JavaScript to handle visibility.

Here is a sample code.

```js
let openPopup = document.getElementById('show-pop-up')
let closePopup = document.getElementById('close-pop-up')

openPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('pop-up').style.display = 'block'
  openPopup.style.display = 'none'
})

closePopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('pop-up').style.display = 'none'
  openPopup.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```css
#pop-up {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">
    <h5 id="pop-up-title">Pop up sample title.</h5>
    <div class="pop-up-content">
        <p>This is a sample pop up content.</p>
    </div>
    <button id="close-pop-up">Close Pop Up</button>
</div>

<button id="show-pop-up">Show Pop Up</button>
```